# WSL2: file permissions unknown on a samba share

Tags: permissions, samba, wsl2

On my windows, I have my y: mapped on a samba share. On this share, I can read/write files, even if I'm not allowed to see files permission.

On my WSL Ubuntu-20.04, I try to map this drive:

```
$ sudo mount -t drvfs y: /mnt/test/ -o metadata,rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=22,fmask=11
```

I can access this share, and even write new file in it, but I'm unable to do anything with files already present on it because permissions are unknown

```
$ touch /mnt/test/outbox/test.txt
$ ls -la /mnt/test/outbox/
ls: cannot access '/mnt/test/outbox/foo.txt': Permission denied
drwxr-xr-x 1 myuser myuser 512 Jan 26 16:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 myuser myuser 512 Oct  7  2019 ..
-????????? ? ?       ?         ?            ? foo.txt
-rwxr--r-- 1 myuser myuser   0 Jan 26 17:05 test.txt
```

What can I do to be able to modify/delete my foo.txt directly from my Ubuntu WSL? (as I can do from my Windows)

Thanks

Comment: could you maybe add your samba share's config to the question? It might show insight in what's wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. I'm not administrator of this share.

Comment: @cyanat I wasn't able to reproduce when trying this with my CIFS shares from another Windows machine.  I tried it with both drives that were accessible to my current user as well as one that required credentials.  Both worked fine when mounted this way -- I first mapped the share to `Y:`, then mounted in WSL as `drvfs` with the same options. I actually was able to just copy your command verbatim since I already had a `/mnt/test` set up.  If I get a chance, I'll see if I can try a CIFS share on my openSUSE box.

Comment: Thank for you feedback. Indeed, on a real Ubuntu (without WSL), I use cifs to mount the share, and it works correctly.

Comment: @cyanat In that case, can you just install `cifs-utils` and then mount as CIFS under WSL?

Comment: @cyanat Also don't forget to tag me in replies -- I just happened to see this one since I didn't get a notification of your last comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds really appreciate your concern! In fact, when looking how to mount a cifs share on wsl, I only get reseult requesting using drvfs. But your are right using cifs-utils to directly mount a cifs share seems to work like a charm, even with WSL. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in the comments, but a few notes for anyone else that comes across this:

- The solution turned out to be fairly straightforward -- Mount the samba drive share directly into WSL2 using `cifs-utils` rather than mounting the mapped drive via `drvfs`.  For Ubuntu, at least (other distro packages may vary slightly):

  ```
  sudo apt install cifs-utils
  sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<share_user> //share.server/path/to/share /mnt/test
  ```
- Troubleshooting was a bit more difficult, since the drive being shared was not under the control of the OP, and we weren't able to obtain information on the configuration of the share.  If someone else comes across this and has a configuration-bsaed solution, please do share it as well.
- For me, mapping a Windows (non-domain) samba share into Windows then mounting that share via `drvfs` worked fine, so we do feel it's something unique to the configuration.